# Street Fighter 4, India Stage Not Available on XBOX 360?

Tags: xbox-360, super-street-fighter-iv

I have Super Street Fighter IV XBox 360. I can not find India stage on that. I believe I have seen that stage on PC though. Is there any difference in PC vs XBOX 360 version of Street Fighter? Is this hidden stage of something?

Comment: On the stage select screen, which stage do you see on the first row, second from the right?

Comment: @pushasha thanks for the reply. I guess I found the problem. I have Street Fighter IV. I didn't knew there are other versions like Super Street Fighter IV and Super Street Fighter IV Arcade Edition. India stage is added in Super Street Fighter which I don't have. :P

Comment: If that's the case, you should either post an answer and select it, or delete the question so it doesn't stay open unanswered.